# How to delete an answer permanently?

Tags: discussion, answers

What should I do if I want to delete my answer completely instead of the regular delete which just locks the answer?

Comment: There is no such thing as "locking" an answer, so I'm not sure what you mean.

A deleted answer will still be visible to you, moderators, and the very high rep folks.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by "locked". It gets frozen but still visible.

Comment: It isn't visible to most of the community, you know.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do this, the contact us link at the foot of the page will let you contact Stack Exchange, however you need to remember that once you post an answer it is effectively owned by the community so if it it useful to others it may be that we need to keep it.